# Display Read more on the same line as v-html

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a text that contains some HTML, and then I use the `v-html` to display the text. Since the text is rather long, I need a `Read more` that the user can click on. The `Read more` must be on the same line as the text.

The code becomes like this:

```html
<div v-html="some-variable-containing-html"></div>
<a @click="makeMoreTextVisible()">Read more</a>
```

Since I want the `Read more` to start exactly where the HTML text ends, I would normally use `display:inline`, but here it does not work.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The `div` is `display:block` by default, which starts the element on its own line, pushing `Read more` to the next line.

You could change the `div` to a `span`, which is `display:inline` by default. This assumes that the HTML variable doesn't contain an element that pushes elements to the next line like the original `div`.

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VwmKevV)

If your HTML variable contains `display:block` elements (such as `div` or `p`), you could apply a class to the HTML container that forces its last child element (with [`:nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)) to `display:inline`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container" v-html="myHtml"></div>
    <a @click="makeMoreTextVisible()">Read more</a>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.container {
  display: inline;
}
.container :nth-last-child(1) {
  display: inline;
}
</style>
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/abBmdZY)

Comment: You nailed it! I am impressed! Thank you tony19!